# Python - YouTube API v3 - How do I get just the video ID of the top search result?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get just the video id of the top search result as a variable.

This is what I've got:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
api_key = 'API_KEY'
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

request = youtube.search().list(
    part='id',
    maxResults=1,
    q='surfing',
    type='video',
    fields='items/id'
    )

response = request.execute()

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    'id': {
        'kind': 'youtube#video', 
        'videoId': '_qbPlSXat4w'
    }
}
```

You just want to get the 'videoId' right?
Try it:

```
print(response['items'][0]['id']['videoId'])
```